# Use of org.apache.httpcomponents in Websphere 8.x

Tags: websphere, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

maybe has someone the same problem.

We want use in our Application *org.apache.httpcomponents* in IBM WebSphere 8.x in Version 4.2.x ( org.apache.httpcore 4.2.4 and org.apache.httpclient 4.2.5 ). If we do that, we get an error [java.lang.VerifyError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html). The reason is: IBM uses [apache.httpcomponents](http://hc.apache.org/) in old version 4.0.1 even in Websphere. But We want the old version not use ( Version 4.0.1 was 2009 releases ) . IBM knows that problem and recommends the use of shared library. That works, when you use Rational products for developing. We use eclipse with WTP for developing with websphere. Unfortunately you can't define shared library with WTP.

Has anybody an idea, or other solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing your development against the WAS liberty profile?  it would be an overall better experience and be an alternative to the shared library approach at development time.

Comment: Sorry, meant this to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: this may be a possibility. We needed a schedule machanism and liberty profile does not support this. ;-(